# Dell Optiplex GX280 - HDD from SFF

Tags: hard-drive, dell

Can I simply take the current HDD from my gx280 SFF desktop and put it within the full-sized model of the same gx280 computer and expect it to work perfectly? Or will there be differences in hardware or drivers that will need to be addressed?

Mike

Answer (score 2):

SATA HDDs are SATA HDDs, no matter the size/form factor.

Unlike previous standards, the connectors are always the same.

So, yes, any SATA HDD can be re-purposed in a different computer that still supports SATA.

Proper settings in the firmware (UEFI or BIOS) should be in place. Usually there's no need to change drive mode but AHCI is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

While the hardware may be entirely functional, software might not be.

Specifically, if you had Windows installed on both computers,
you might find that Windows from the old computer will become
inactivated on the new computer and may require to be re-activated.
You may also need to install drivers for components that didn't
exist on the old computer.

If both computers came with Windows installed OEM, the reactivation
of Windows may be automatic. If the new computer came with a
serial-number on a sticker or somewhere, better not loose it,
as you may be required to enter it manually.

In more complicated cases, you may need to call Microsoft Support
to unblock the problem.